# Moments of random special unitary matrices

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices

This should be both well-known and probably easy, but I was wondering if the following is known (and, if so, how to easily calculate the thing or where to read about how to calculate it):

what is $$\int_{\mathrm{SU}(n)} \mathrm{tr}(U^k) dU?$$ (Here by "$dU$" I mean normalized Haar measure.)

Of course for $k$ not a multiple of $n$ the integral is zero. (It's always zero on $\mathrm{U}(n)$ by the same argument.) Also by Weyl's integration formula (i.e. averaging over conjugates of $U$) one immediately reduces to performing the integral over diagonal matrices, but I didn't see a way to get a clean answer out.

Apologies if this is easy! I just couldn't find a good reference.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the dimension of the invariant subspace of the $k^{th}$ tensor power of the defining representation of $\text{SU}(n)$. This is at least good enough to figure out the answer when $n = 2$; you get the Catalan numbers. In general maybe you can say something involving Schur-Weyl duality.

Comment: Schur-Weyl duality is the key word! One gets something like $k!\cdot \frac{0!\cdots (n-1)!}{(k/n)!\cdots (k/n+n-1)!}$ via the hook-length formula (I think the only relevant representation of S_k is the one corresponding to a $k/n\times n$ box?), but I have to write this down to check. At least it's OK in the n=2 case. Thanks!! I totally missed this interpretation!

Comment: Such integrals crop up in lattice gauge theory, for which see, e.g. Creutz's book.

Comment: Wait --- now I'm sure I'm being dumb --- but the above computes the average of $\mathrm{tr}(U)^k$ rather than that of $\mathrm{tr}(U^k)$, no?

Comment: Oops. Yes. The thing you've actually written down is some higher Frobenius-Schur indicator, and if you know how to express $\text{tr}(U^k)$ as a linear combination of characters of representations of $\text{U}(n)$ (which is some exercise in symmetric function theory) then you just need to extract the multiplicity of the trivial representation again.

Comment: Newton's identities will help.

Comment: Yep! But I guess I was hoping for a cleaner answer. Via this route one only has to compute the multiplicity of the trivial representation in something of shape $(\wedge^a V)^x\otimes (\wedge^b V)^y$, where V is the fundamental representation, and I suppose that's again Schur-Weyl duality (though I don't know anything about the restriction map induced by $S_\lambda\to S_n$ (where $S_\lambda := S_{\lambda_1}\times\cdots\times S_{\lambda_\ell}$ is the subgroup corresponding to the partition $\lambda$ of $n$), so I can't say I know how), but then the resulting sum looks like it'll be a mess!

Comment: You can view it as the trace of a $k$-cycle in $S_k$ acting on the invariant subspace of $V^{\otimes k}$.

Comment: Nice --- then Schur-Weyl duality does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have stared at the Weyl integration formula longer --- it's clear from that that, once $k\gg_n 1$, the integral is zero. In fact [this article](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869307003420/1-s2.0-S0021869307003420-main.pdf?_tid=485ff84e-8af5-11e4-895a-00000aab0f6c&acdnat=1419374861_b065384d2f6ee608801b6f5a9ee645ff) shows that the integral vanishes once $k\geq 2n-1$ (it already vanishes when $k$ is not a multiple of $n$). Hence the only case left is $k=n$, and, if I've interpreted their result correctly, the answer is $(-1)^{n-1}$. This could almost certainly have been read off from the formula in this special case, of course.

[To explain the title, note that the element $\int_{\mathrm{SU}(n)} U^n dU$ commutes with all of $\mathrm{SU}(n)$ and must therefore be a scalar, so it suffices to know its trace.]